# Going through every row of a date and giving a week number

Tags: sas

I have a set of data containing dates that have been sorted out say from 25th June 2016 till 24th August 2016. I have to add a 'Week' column that numbers the starting week from 1 and incrementing by 1 every time a new week comes in that start on a Sunday. I know a little coding but I have no experience with SAS so I am having a lot of trouble with this. The first week would be a little struggle since it could be that the date does not start with a Sunday and I can't simply reiterate the code 7 times. But the week after would not be too hard since it's only doing a loop everytime the date meets with a new Sunday.

I have a lot of things in my mind, I have been googling and tried coding but to no avail. If anyone could explain to me, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample data, the output you're trying to produce, and any code you've tried already.

Comment: You also need to clarify if every day between the 2 dates is always included, it can make a difference to the answer.  Have a look at the `intck` function, this will most likely help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data out;
set in;
Week = 1;
if weekday(date) = 1 then Week + 1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the built in WEEK function. Find the first week as your base number and then subtract that to get the increment needed. ie if your first week is 5, then

`Week_want = week(date) - 5;`